# Gnuplot: plot from number and from file

Tags: file, for-loop, plot, gnuplot

I have several files, each one with the same number of rows. Files are named as "something_integer.txt" like "a100.txt", "a200.txt", "a300.txt"... and so (integer is every 100 and something is always the same). Every row is connected in time with the same row of the other files but is not connected with others rows.

I want to plot all row 1 of all files in a single graph, all row 2 of all files in an other single graph (but overlayed to the previous one) and so. How can I do this with gnuplot?

I know that I need to use a for loop. I was thinking in something like (just for row 1 and row 2):

```
 do for [i=100:5000:100] {
   plot sprintf('something_%d.txt',i) every 1::1::1 using ¿¿¿¿¿????:5,
        sprintf('something_%d.txt',i) every 1::2::2 using ¿¿¿¿¿????:5
}
```

but questions arise:

1. Where I put "¿¿¿¿¿????" is because I want to plot as y the value of column 5 but as x the value i, not the value of column i. How can you do that?
2. If every time that continues the loop I have a plot instruction, will previous points be erased? will they be connected as I want?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is easy: you have to use parenthesis `using (i):5`

If I understand correctly, for the second one, you have to move the loop inside the `plot`:

```
plot for [i=100:5000:100] \
    sprintf('something_%d.txt',i) every 1::1::1 using (i):5, \
    sprintf('something_%d.txt',i) every 1::2::2 using (i):5
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Not exactly. This is ok for beginning but I would like to connect all points of row 1 between them with a line and all points of row 2 with another line. With this, every point is like a "serie of data".

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to do this within gnuplot is overkill (but I like overkill solutions!). You're better off with some preprocessing in bash using `awk` or something alike. However, you can still use the `awk` command from within your gnuplot code. This does what you want:

```
loop = ""; do for [i=100:5000:100] { loop = sprintf("%s %i", loop, i) }

file(n) = "< for i in ".loop."; do awk -v i=$i 'NR==".n."{print i, $5}' a${i}.txt; done"

plot file(1) w l, file(2) w l
```

`n` is the row you are selecting, so that `file(1)` selects row no. 1 in all your files, and `file(2)` selects row no. 2 in all your files, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but as I understand your comment, @bibi's solution would be ok, except the points are not connected by lines. Concerning @Miguels solution, you can do it in gnuplot only, no need for external tools.

Already since gnuplot 5.0.0 (2015) you can plot `with table` to files and datablocks.
With the following you are merging, actually, interlacing your rows 1 and 2 from different files (Note, row indices in gnuplot are 0-based).
Once you have your rows from your different files in *one* datablock you can address the lines easily via `every 2::0` and `every 2::1` which will connect the datapoints with lines.

**Data:**

```
# SO36121176_100.txt
1  2  3  4  11
1  2  3  4  21
1  2  3  4  31
1  2  3  4  41
```

```
# SO36121176_200.txt
1  2  3  4  12
1  2  3  4  22
1  2  3  4  32
1  2  3  4  42
```

```
# SO36121176_300.txt
1  2  3  4  13
1  2  3  4  23
1  2  3  4  33
1  2  3  4  43
```

```
# SO36121176_400.txt
1  2  3  4  14
1  2  3  4  24
1  2  3  4  34
1  2  3  4  44
```

**Script:**

```
### merge rows from different files into one datablock
reset session

myFile(i) = sprintf("SO36121176_%d.txt",i)

set table $Data
    do for [i=100:400:100] {
        plot myFile(i) u (i):5 every ::0::1 w table
    }
unset table

plot for [i=1:2 ]$Data u 1:2 every 2::i-1 w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("Rows %d",i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

The datablock `$Data` will look like this:

```
 100     11
 100     21
 200     12
 200     22
 300     13
 300     23
 400     14
 400     24
```

[image]